# Pasting a long string of text into Heroku rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-cli

Pasting any string longer than a couple hundred characters into a Heroku rails console takes forever. The more characters are pasted, the slower it goes, letter by letter. Is there a way to make this run at a reasonable speed?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Run this in project directory

```
heroku run 'bundle exec rails c -- --nomultiline'
```

Answer (score 8):

This is [a problem with Ruby's 2.7's default multi-line pasting in irb](https://github.com/ruby/irb/issues/43). Here's how to resolve it.

```
$ heroku run -a my_app_name bash
$ echo 'IRB.conf[:USE_MULTILINE] = false' > ~/.irbrc
$ bin/rails c
> <Now you can paste the text in and it will go quickly>
```